# Animated plot of the trajectory of a particle on unit circle

Tags: plotting, animation

Let $P$ be a particle moving on the circumference of a circle, of unit radius, such that at time $t$ the particle is displaced through an angle $\psi(t)=\sin(0.5t)$ from its rest position. It would be useful to have an animated plot of the trajectory of the particle. How does one go about producing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[], PointSize[0.04], Red, Point[{Cos[0.5 t], Sin[0.5 t]}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}],
 {t, 0, 100, 0.1}, AnimationRate -> 4
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may wish to play with the colour, increment and AnimationRate. Look up Animate.

Reading your question again did you mean this?

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[], PointSize[0.04], Red, 
   Point[{Cos[Sin[0.5 t]], Sin[Sin[0.5 t]]}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}],
 {t, 0, 100, 0.1}, AnimationRate -> 4
 ]
```

Same picture but now the particle oscillates.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a gif of it

```
Table[
  Graphics[
   {
    {Thickness[.006], Circle[]},
    {PointSize[.03], Red, {Cos@#, Sin@#} &@Sin[.5 t] // Point}
    }
   ],
  {t, 0, 4 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/100}
  ];
ListAnimate@%
SetDirectory["YourDirectory"]; Export["Oscillator.gif", %%]
```

[image]

where we have $0 \leq t \leq 4 \pi$ because the period of $\sin(0.5 t)$ is $T = 4 \pi$.

Comment: Yes better than mine. Why do you only go to 2Pi?  If you go to further the oscillation can go in the lower part of the circle.

Comment: @Hugh You're right, that was just a habit because I've made this animation quite a few times, but always with the period of $2 \pi$, whereas the period in this case is $4\pi$.  I'll change it.